# Blender 2.81a: No Smoke or Fire With Quick / Solid Render

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, fire

I think this is a bug. Can anyone help with a workaround or confirm that it does not work at the moment?

In the default scene, if I select the cube, then add via menu "Object | Quick Effects | Quick Smoke", I can see the effect in the view port. With "Cycles" or "Eevee". They both work.

[image]

But when I try to render it with "Cycles", I got only a solid cube.

[image]

If I try to render it with "Eevee", I got only a smokey, blurred cube.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender MantaFlow ... no visible result!](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118942/blender-mantaflow-no-visible-result)

Comment: No. Baking of my smoke/fire makes no different.
The animation is there... but it won't render it.