# Blender 2.82 Baked Domain Mantaflow Issue

Tags: rendering, physics

I had 2.79b before today (26 Feb 2020) but after so many cool tutorials I updated today!

I've looked at the other questions but frankly those + watching the latest tutorial showing exactly what to select, etc. still no progress here.

(if you think my hardware is part of the issue somehow: i7 8700k cpu, 1080ti gpu + 32gb ram + 1tb hdd+512gb SSD.)

Tutorial mentioned:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QcsxPAbGsKM&feature=youtu.be
At the moment I don't see how to do a screenshot but I can use OBS and record a video (idk lol...ugh I have closed and re-opened Blender 2 times and still no results rendering from the re-baking and all).

So the problem I have is that no particles are rendered/displayed in the viewport after baking is done.  Yes liquid is checked (and rechecked after another person on a different question pointed out that it may look checked initially but in fact is not recognized as checked when baking).  Others have asked this same question but the difference I'm seeing is simply they got resolved and I have not after making the same adjustments and changes to bakes, order of baking the data 1st then mesh, etc.  I don't see what's going on that could mean no particles ever are rendered.  Just out of the box I haven't even tried using the new brushes so maybe I downloaded an alpha version?  Let me know if more information is needed.

I've managed to add the .blend file thankfully. 
[image]

Comment: Can you describe what is the issue you're having? You should [edit] the question to add more details. Does this answer it? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118942/blender-mantaflow-no-visible-result?rq=1

Comment: Hi. You seem to have added all the supporting information to your question without describing the initial problem.

Comment: Thanks I managed to forget that...adding that in now.